# How do you left-align and right-align items on the same line in a Google Document?

Tags: google-docs

I want to have something written in the top-left corner and top-right corners of my document. So I want some text aligned to the right, some to the left, at the same height. I could do it with spamming the space bar, but then if I change the font size or anything it will be broken again.

Is there any way to do this more neatly?

Answer (score 131):

1. Make sure you have `View > Show ruler` checked.
2. In the ruler above your document, click where you want the right-most character of the right-aligned section to be. Then select the option that pops up: "Add right tab-stop".  (In the example image in step 3, it is all the way at the right margin.)

   [image: add tab stop]
3. Then, on that line, type your left-most text as normal, then hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key until your cursor is located at the tab-stop you just created and type your text. You should notice that it fills in from the right. Now you shouldn't have issues when you change your font.

   [image: results]

(More at [Page setup](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/183618))

Comment: Do you have to create one for each and every line? Also, is there any way to do it without drag and drop? I see its impossible to align multiple lines neatly along the same line.

Comment: if you go to the beginning of a line which has a right tab-stop setup and press Enter, the new line will have the same tab-stop too.

Comment: To offer more context, "Modern word processors generalize this concept by offering tab stops that have an alignment attribute and cause the text to be automatically aligned at left, at right or center of the tab stop itself." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop

Comment: Nothing pops up when I click the ruler.

Comment: Thank you. I spent so long trying to figure this out myself. Why is this not available as a menu command? Cardinal sin of UI design. Every action should be available in the menu.

Comment: @MattD, I wasn't getting the options either when clicking on the grayed-out part of the ruler (past the Right Indent arrow, or even on top of it). I had to click somewhere in the white part of the ruler in order to get the tab-stop options, then move my tab-stop to where I wanted it after it was added.

Comment: I noticed that the 'Add right tab-stop' option pops up when I am editing in the main document area. It does not pop up when I am editing in the 'header' section. I hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot seem to get this to work when inside a table cell

Answer (score 9):

You can use a table (with 1 row and 2 columns) without border.