# Is it possible to use tab stops in the header of a Google Doc?

Tags: google-docs

I learned from a [previous question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51121/how-do-you-left-align-and-right-align-items-on-the-same-line-in-a-google-documen) how to use tab stops to left- and right-align separate strings of text on the same line in a Google Doc. I'd like to do that in a header. Is it possible? I've added the tab stop, but it only seems to affect text in the body of the Document, not the header.

In the meantime I'm using a table as a hack, but the obligatory carriage returns before and after the table make it a clumsy solution.